# Close Bootstrap modal in controller after getting response from server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When the form is submitted, a call is made out to the server and modal is being shown. When the response from the server is a success, the modal has to be closed 
and a new page is loaded.

I've tried ng-show, ng-if to enable/disable based on the value in the controller, but this does not dismiss the modal backdrop. I am able to close the modal on the same page using data-dismiss="modal", but how do I do this from the controller section before navigating to a new page?

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">    
    <img src="img/processing.gif" id="ajaxSpinnerImage" title="working...">
  </div>
</div>
```

When Submit button is clicked

```
<button type="submit" data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#myModal"  ng-click=" formsubmit(orderForm.$valid); ></i>  
Place Order </button>
```

Call to the server from the Controller

```
 $scope.formsubmit = function (isValid) {
      if (isValid) {                              
                  $http.post($scope.url).
                    success(function (data, status) {  

                        //NEED TO CLOSE THE MODAL HERE
                   //navigating to a new page now
                   window.location.assign("NewPageToNavigate.html");

                    })
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

Wire this Bootstrap modal option to the server resopnse and the modal will close:

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
```

[More info and options on the Bootstrap documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-methods).

Regarding the removal of the body and backdrop classes, check your code as Bootstrap under normal conditions should remove those on firing the method above.

Comment: I also had to add this to remove the backdrop after the page was loaded.         
                                                                     
                  $('body').removeClass('modal-open');
                  $('.modal-backdrop').remove();

Comment: Ok, strange. Firing the Bootstrap method should do that for you.

Comment: Instead of `.trigger( "click" );`, one can use `.click()`. Also, this may double-trigger modals. If you want a 100% complete way to hide **ANY** modal, use `$('.modal').filter(':visible').modal('hide')`.

Comment: @NathanielFlick I saw the update and I'm commenting on it. `$('[data-dismiss="modal"]').trigger( "click" );` can tell the same modal to close multiple times. Or even tell it to close modals that aren't open at all.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel sorry i added my comment before seeing your post. I didn't see the double click issue you mentioned with OPTION 2, but if there is an issue you could use stopPropagation, per jQuery docs for trigger. I still haven't found a better way in Bootstrap docs. Foundation has a method that closes the currently open modal more dependably.

Comment: The issue is that `$('[data-dismiss="modal"]')` will fetch all the link and buttons, and will trigger the click on them. Imagine that you have a close button (usual for modals) and a link to also close the same modal. You're telling the modal to close twice. Or even worse: you have something like this: `<a href="#" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#last_modal">Back</a>`. Your code will close the modal twice and open the `#last_modal`, my fix won't.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161862/discussion-between-nathaniel-flick-and-ismael-miguel).

Comment: After testing (https://www.bootply.com/dIG90LalIk to see the test code), I've figured that `.modal('hide');` won't trigger the `hidden.bs.modal` event on hidden modals. This removes the need for the `.filter(':visible')`. I was wrong and though it would trigger the event on hidden modals when you tried to close them. A plain `.modal('hide')` is enough.

Comment: Thanks much for your input @IsmaelMiguel

Answer (score 0):

Close the modal after the response has been received in the controller

```
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('body').removeClass('modal-open');
$('.modal-backdrop').remove();
```